# Do resurrected characters automatically re-attune to their magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, character-death, resurrection, attunement

In the basic rules (Pg. 58) as well as in the DMG (Pg. 138), the section on attunement states (emphasis mine):

> A creature’s attunement to an item ends if the creature
>   no longer satisfies the prerequisites for attunement, if
>   the item has been more than 100 feet away for at least
>   24 hours, **if the creature dies**, or if another creature
>   attunes to the item.

By this logic, if a player character dies, then their attunement to any magic items would end. If that character is resurrected, for example with the *Revivify* or *Raise Dead* spells, will their attunement be restored along with their life?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**If that character is resurrected, for example with the Revivify or Raise Dead spells, will their attunement be restored along with their life?**

**No**. If a character dies they lose the attunement as stated in the rules you quote. They will then have to re-attune to every item they were previously attuned to, which may not be possible if someone else has already done so in the intervening time or some other prerequisite has changed.

An exception would be a Wish spell used to re-create a Resurrection effect but with an additional "and re-attuned to all their items" clause, basically by changing all the pre-requisites to what they need to be and de-attuning anyone who attuned to the items in the meantime. However be careful with the wording as a clever DM will take you literally and there may be some un-desired consequences. Also this would be an effect that had the more dramatic consequences to the caster of making a Wish as it is beyond merely duplicating a spell.

Answer (score 14):

No. Why would it? There's only one method provided for attuning to items:

> Attuning
>   to a magic item requires that you spend a short rest
>   concentrating on it (this can’t be the same short rest
>   used to learn an item’s properties).

And, as you included in your question, attunement ends if you die. You can, of course, re-attune once you've been revived, but "being resurrected" won't cause attunement automatically.